# How to use Realm objects with Swift generic type?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, realm

I have generic class `Child`. At some point I want to check if `Child` object conforms to `MyProtocol` and I get the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS. At this point I dont know if this is related to Swift or to Realm library.

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
}


class Child<O: Object>: NSObject {
  override init() {
    let _ = O() as? MyProtocol   // here I get error
  }
}


class ChildCache: Object {

}
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug in the Realm Swift library. Can you file a ticket on our GitHub issue tracker (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues), and enclose a project we can use to reproduce the crash? Many thanks.

Comment: ok, i will do it